# How do I set up datasource for JBoss plugin using Maven to run tests with Arquillian?

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to make work arquillian tests with jboss managed server and IBM DB2 database.

For now I'm stuck on creating datasource. Since JBoss is unpacked on each run, I'm trying to add driver and datasource configuration into pom.xml in order to Maven take care of creating proper configurations on JBoss and resulting section looks like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>arquillian-jboss-managed</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- JBoss server itself -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- adding datasource -->           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-driver</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <!-- groupId and artifactId aren't global, I've got jar on defined path  -->
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>db2</groupId>
                            <artifactId>db2cc</artifactId>
                            <name>db2jcc4.jar</name>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-datasource</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=MyDataSource</address>
                            <properties>
                                <connection-url>jdbc:db2://host:port/database</connection-url>
                                <jndi-name>MyDataSource</jndi-name>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <pool-name>MyDataSource</pool-name>
                                <user-name>db2inst1</user-name>
                                <password>pass</password>
                                <driver-name>db2jcc4.jar</driver-name>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Yet I've got an error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:add-resource
>   (add-datasource) on project testrunner: Could not execute goal
>   add-resource. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
>   "address" => [], "operation" => "read-attribute", "name" =>
>   "launch-type" }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not
>   connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out

I guess the problem is JBoss isn't started at the moment Maven tries to apply configuration parameters or simply doesn't listen to required port.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason to unpack the JBoss distribution on every run? You need not do this and you could use an existing JBoss instance.

Comment: No specific reason except for I wanted the project to be portable without much tuning

Comment: Well, it would be better to omit that objective for a simpler build. Your problem is indeed that the server is not started, and you'll need map the goals to start and stop the server as well in addition to configuring the data source.

Comment: Looks like JBoss is running during test phase. At least netstat shows active connection at port 9999.

Comment: I'm trying to apply configuration way before that phase though.

Comment: @VineetReynolds, thanks for your help! It turned out it was not hard at all to start and shutdown jboss using jboss-as-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing this problem was as simple as adding start and shutdown goals to jboss-as-maven-plugin executions before and after other configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>start-server</id>
    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>                                
    <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
<!-- copying driver and datasource here -->
<execution>
    <id>shutdown-server</id>
    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>                                
    <goals>
        <goal>shutdown</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Also this start goal downloads it's own JBoss instance if one is not provided. So this part is not needed any more:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- skipped -->
</plugin>
```